# Не сохраняет добавленые значения C# и SQL

Tags: c#, sql

У меня есть две формы Form1 и Form4, из Form1 я по кнопке могу перейти на Form4  Когда закрываю форму "Form4" значения заполненные пользователем сохраняются, а когда выходишь из программы, то есть закрываю полностью Form1 и Form4, то все значения пропадают. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet2);

        }

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "database1DataSet2.Table". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet2.Table);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableBindingSource.AddNew();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            tableTableAdapter.Update(database1DataSet2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: возможно вы забыли `commit` ? Код картинокй - зло

Comment: Значит, при выходе из программы не выполняется явное закрытие формы. А надеяться на автоматическую выгрузку в этом случае не надо...

Comment: Наверняка БД копируется при каждом билде в папку с готовых экзешником. Именно с этой копией работает ваша программа. Очень частая ошибка.

Comment: Исползуете `EF` для подключения БД?

Comment: @ A K, Смотрел, не помогло, поэтому снова спрашиваю

Comment: А почему вы уверены, что при закрытии формы значения сохраняются? Вы это смотрели в базе? Или видели в программе новые значения?

Comment: @ A K, это я смотрел значения в программе, делаю таким образом, Открываю сначала Form1, потом Form4, когда я ввиду какие-то значения в строку в Form4, потом сохраняю, закрываю Form4, но не закрываю Form1, то при повторном открытии Form4, у меня новые значения показывает, то есть сохраненные, но если я закрою Form4 и Form1, и потом сново запущу программу, то введенных мной строки уже не отобразятся

Comment: Проверять наличие данных надо в БД, а не на форме. Данные на форме могут быть из памяти взяты, а не из базы данных.

Comment: @tym32167, а как сделать чтобы брал значения с базы, не подскажете?

Comment: Пройти обучение по работе с БД, это отдельная большая тема. Но вам оно сейчас не надо, вам сейчас надо понять, что у вас не работает.

Comment: @EdwardKamalov попробуйте запускать программу не из студии по F5 / Ctrl F5, а напрямую из bin. Если при этом данные будут сохраняться - значит, ваш вопрос - дубликат. И приведите в вопросе connection string, на всякий случай.