# Не сохраняет добавленные значения C# в SQL

Tags: c#, sql

У меня есть две формы `Form1` и `Form4`, из `Form1` я по кнопке могу перейти на `Form4`.  Когда закрываю форму `Form4` значения, заполненные пользователем, сохраняются, а когда выходишь из программы, то есть закрываю полностью `Form1` и `Form4`, то все значения пропадают. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать? (Новичок в этом деле)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet2);

        }

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "database1DataSet2.Table". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet2.Table);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableBindingSource.AddNew();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            tableTableAdapter.Update(database1DataSet2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В удалённой вами [копии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812875/213987) вопроса вам рекомендовали посмотреть [вот эту причину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426203/213987). Вы проверяли?